# How to generate XSD from Class with restrictions

Tags: c#, xsd

Is there a way how to decorate property of datacontract object, so the generated xsd will contain MaxLenght restriction?

E.g. I can imagine I need something like this:

```
[XmlElement(MaxLengthAttribute = "12")]
public string Name;
```

and something like this should be included in the output from xsd.exe:

```
<xs:element name="name">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value = "12"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Is there a way to do it? To define the restrictions in C# class in such way, the xsd.exe tool will generate the restrictions into the xsd file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way of doing that.